# Issue with increasing a number in td by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an input field that takes the name of the book, gets the price from database and puts the result in a table.

Now if a book has been chosen more than one time, then I want the quantity to increase and then show the price for that number of that book.

Here is the code:

```
<div>
     <input type="text" id="book_item" value="<?php echo $books['book_name']; ?>"/> 
     <input type="button" id="addbook" value="Apply" onclick="addBookToTable()" />          
</div>

<table id="booktable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Book Name</th>
        <th id="quantity">Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Remove Book</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="price"></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>  

<script>
     var quantity = $("#quantity").children('td').eq(1).text();

    // not sure how to check if the book is already in the table or not
    // if it is, then it should just show the name of the book
    // only one time and increase the quantity number.
<script>
```

I appreciate any code sample or comments that can solve the issue.

Comment: When you select `$("#quantity")` you will get `<th id="quantity">` element, so you can't find any `td` chiildren. First you should get parent e.g `$("#quantity").parent('table')` and then look for `tbody` and `tr` or `td`

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this only by displaying databases results, there's no need to use javascript client side, you should do your checks on the original array and then produce the table that the client side will show.

If instead you're adding books on the fly (and your input on top seems to suggest as such) then the best way to accomplish this is by modifying the "addBookToTable" procedure so that it checks the entire table to see if there's already a book with that name on it and eventually it raises the quantity instead of adding a new line.

EDIT:

Well, unless the books are in a particular order, there's no going around a linear search of the whole list:

```
$('#booktable tr').each(function() {
  var children = $(this).children('td');
  if(children.length > 1) {
    if(children.first().text() == MyNewBookTitle) {
      var quantityChild = $(children[1]);
      quantityChild.text( parseInt(quantityChild.text()) + 1 );
    }
  }
});
```

Note that you shouldn't use the id "price" in the td since ids are supposed to be unique.

Also, to avoid the awkwardness of using `first()` or `children[1]` you should give your tds a class name so that in the code above you could use a filter:

```
children.filter('.title')
```

and

```
children.filter('.quantity')
```

Comment: Actually you are correct, I am adding the books to the table one by one in side the addBookToTable function. Now what I am not sure is how to check the table to see if the book name exist. Do you have any JavaScript code suggestion or any page that can help? Thank you.

Comment: I applied the suggested code in my program but unfortunately seems not to work yet.

Comment: Please describe the problem in detail and give a jsFiddle that reproduce the problem at hand.

Comment: @a-rama Below sample code from Vladu Lonut is working fine for checking the quantity of the book however before checking the quantity I need to get the input value (book name) from the input and with that I have to check if it exists in side the table. Now the problem is that I am not sure how to do this process in Java Script. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this selector

```
    var bookName="any bookName " ;
    var theBookTD = $("#booktable tr td:nth-child(1):contains('"+ bookName+"')");

if (theBookTD.length>0 ) {
//the book already exists in table
    var theBookQuantity = theBookTD.next().first().text();
}else {
// the book doesn't exist in table;
}
```

take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/buuk2zjf/3/

Comment: Can I ask, what is the ('Book Name') in your code? Because the book name should be dynamic as there is huge list of book names coming from database!

Comment: var bookName="any bookName " ;$("#booktable tr td:nth-child(1):contains('"+ bookName+"')");

Comment: I tried the sample code you suggested, but seems not to work with my table.

Comment: @vladu-lonut I tried above code, it works for checking the quantity. Now the problem is how to check if the book that is been selected from input exists inside the table? I have tried few code samples but was not successful in checking if the book exists in the table or not. I appreciate any code suggestion and samples.